# One Input, Two Variables, Solve To Equal Input

Tags: linear-algebra

I've never been the best with math, and I've spent about half a day trying to come up with a solution to this, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Solve for $c$ and $a$. The value for $p$ is inputted by the end-user.

$$3c + 4a = p$$

Examples:

$$(168)(3) + (124)(4) = 1000$$
$$(152)(3) + (111)(4) = 900$$
$$(136)(3) + (98)(4) = 800$$

I need to find a solution to $a$ and $c$, where $3c$ is *greater than or equal to* $4a$. The products of $3c$ and $4a$ should be as close together as possible, assuming they are not equal.

I'm not sure what other information would be helpful here, but I'm happy to answer any questions you may have.

Thank you very much for your time!

p.s. Here is what I'm actually working on, in case you're curious:
https://hastebin.com/voyuvobevu.gs

Comment: Is $cx3$ supposed to me $c$ times $3$?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: $a=p/4, c=4a/3$

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I should have used addition instead of greater than/equal to signs. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want $3c$ and $4a$ about the same, start with $c=\frac p6$ and $a=\frac p8$.  If $p$ is a multiple of $24$ you are done.  Otherwise, round them up to the next whole number and see how much you are over.  Call it $k$.  If you add $k$ to $c$ and subtract $k$ from $a$ you will get a total that equals $p$.  Finally if the difference between $3c$ and $4a$ exceeds $24$, subtract $4$ from $c$ and add $3$ to $a$ and you will be closer.

As an example, let $p=67$.  Our first division and roundup results in $c=12, a=9, 3c+4a=72$, an excess of $5$.  Adding $5$ to $c$ and subtracting $5$ from $a$ gives us $3\cdot 17+4\cdot 4=67$, but that has $3c=51,4a=16$.  As $51-16=35 \ge 24$ we can use $c=17-4=13, a=4+3=7$, giving $3\cdot 13+4\cdot 7=67, 3c=39,4a=28$

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. *c* should be greater than *or* equal to *a*. I've edited the original post to try and make that clearer, as well as added some more examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, it truly does mean a lot. I did want to let you know that I made a couple updates to the original post, and thought you might like to look through it again to confirm everything you've written is correct.

Again, thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Comment: @Seathre: See the new answer.